# SQL Server Pivot on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the below data in a table

[image]

i want  the data to convert like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when name = 'A' then eng end) as a_eng,
       sum(case when name = 'A' then mat end) as a_mat,
       . . . ,
       sum(case when name = 'B' then eng end) as b_eng,
       sum(case when name = 'B' then mat end) as b_mat,
       . . . 
from t
group by id;
```